# Measurements of the iPhone 7 Plus camera app UI

Tags: iphone

Anyone happens to know the screen ratio of each part of the UI in the iPhone 7 Plus camera app? Like how much screen space does the top part UI take, the center one and the bottom UI. 
I am making an app that resembles the iPhone 7 Plus camera UI and I would like to know the exact measurements.[image]

Comment: Wouldn’t you count pixels using xScope or another graphic tool?

Comment: I am not sure I get you. What do you mean?

Comment: https://xscopeapp.com/ Is the software I use for this

Comment: Ah too bad it is a paid app. Any chance you could do the calculations and post as an answer here?